# Xml parsing in j2me

Tags: java, xml, java-me

I want to do xml parsing in j2me for fetching data (sms, mms, location) from server to mobile. I am using Netbeans 6.8 as an IDE. It is not allowing me to import below 2 file:

```
import org.kxml.*;
import org.kxml.parser.*;
```

When I am trying to import xml it is showing me

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
```

How can I use kxml parser class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have kxml to parse XML in ME env. [Here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_parse_an_XML_file_in_Java_ME_with_kXML) is sample code with proper explanation

[Here](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/kxml/j2me-xml-parser.shtml) is what you exactly need.

Comment: Thank you very much.But i cant able to add kml apis in my application.

Comment: વેલકમ :) <!-- proxy chars -->

Comment: Thank you very much.But i cant able to add kml apis in my application.It is only showing xml and xml.sax aapis.why i cant able to use kml parsing.What shoul i do so that i can use kml parsing apis.plz help me out of this.i am very congused

Comment: It seems you haven't supplied lib get it from [here](http://kxml.objectweb.org/software/downloads/current/kxml.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Lot of XML parser [available](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/). But I suggest KXML is better and download [here](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/). See this [sample code](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/wireless/wi-xmlj2me.zip) for your reference.